# c# code first update datacontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

i am using code first. But i have a problem with update data.

My class is:

```
public class definition : Base
        {
            [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int definition_GroupId { get; set; }
            public int? definition_ParentId { get; set; }
            public string definition_txt { get; set; }
            public bool IsStatic { get; set; }
            public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        }
```

I am using AjaxPost, and i send only Id and definition_txt.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param.definition_txt))
{
    definitionRepository.Attach(param);
    UnitOfWork.Save();
}
```

My repository Attach method is:

```
public void Attach(T entity)
{
    _dbset.Attach(entity);
    DataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Done. But update all colums, i want to update only selected Colums. How can i do?

Comment: Try `DataContext.Entry(entity).Property("definition_txt").IsModified = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loading the entity first from db with Find method, then updating it and saving to db like this:

```
definition originalEntity = _dbset.Find(entity.Id);
originalEntity.definition_txt = entity.definition_txt;
```

Comment: i think, no need to go to the database again.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Update(T entity, string[] columns)
        {
            if (columns != null)
            {
                _dbset.Attach(entity);
                foreach (var item in columns)
                {
                    DataContext.Entry(entity).Property(item).IsModified = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you @DavidG